# UWP App - Azure AD Updated Permission Scopes for Single Sign-On JWT Not Triggering Renewed User Consent

Tags: azure, win-universal-app, single-sign-on, jwt, azure-active-directory

**Summary:**

Our Universal Windows App single-tenant client uses an ASP.NET Web API 2 as a proxy for single-sign on for various Microsoft Office 365 APIs. We use Active Directory for server authentication and the on-behalf-of single sign-on model in our server to exchange tokens for the Office 365 APIs.

**Problem:**

We have updated a permission scope in Azure for the Office 365 API and the user is not prompted to authorize permission for the new scope, nor is the new scope appearing on NEW tokens. What needs to be done to DETECT and ALLOW our users to authorize new permission scopes?

**Additional Details:**

- Our server is hosted in MSFT Azure App Services. I understand the manifest in Azure is auto-generated and does not need to be manually updated to reflect the updated permission scope?
- When the user first logs into the UWP app, they consent to single sign-on permissions associated with the server (eg. Mail.ReadWrite, etc.) which works fine. However, the user consent prompt does not show up again, even after I’ve removed both the client and server apps from my list of consented to apps using
- We use the `WebTokenRequest` and `WebAuthenticationCoreManager` libraries in the client to get the token for the server. I have also tried using `WebAuthenticationBroker` (which is not the correct method for our sign-on architecture) and the ADAL library in our client. None of these libraries are prompting for the updated permission.
- I have also tried adding `wtf.Properties.Add("prompt", "consent");` to our `WebTokenRequest` to force the user to reapprove permissions. This does not work.
- I have also tried restarting the App Service in Azure. This does nothing.

**UPDATED 11/10/16:**
Following is relevant code I've pulled from our app architecture which may help. Additionally, our server utilizes ADAL version 2.24.304111323.

**In our UWP app:**

```
public class AppAuth
{
    WebTokenRequestResult result;
    WebAccount acc;

    async Task<WebTokenRequestResult> GetTokenAsync(WebTokenRequestPromptType promptType = WebTokenRequestPromptType.Default)
    {
        var wtr = new WebTokenRequest(
            provider: "https://login.windows.net",
            scope: "",
            clientId: appClientId,
            promptType: promptType
        );
        wtr.Properties.Add("authority", "https://login.windows.net");
        wtr.Properties.Add("resource", azureWebsiteUrl);

        if (promptType != WebTokenRequestPromptType.ForceAuthentication)
        {
            result = (acc == null) ?
            await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.GetTokenSilentlyAsync(wtr) :
            await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.GetTokenSilentlyAsync(wtr, acc);
        }

        if (promptType == WebTokenRequestPromptType.ForceAuthentication ||
            result?.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.UserInteractionRequired)
        {
            result = (acc == null) ?
            await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wtr) :
            await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wtr, acc);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**In our server:**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    SaveSigninToken = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                }
            });
    }
}

public class TokenChange
{ 
    protected AdUser _user;
    private UserAssertion _assertion;
    private static string _aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string _tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string _appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];
    private string _accessToken;
    public AuthenticationResult AuthResult { get; set; }
    public AdalException AuthException { get; set; }
    private string _emailAddress;
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public bool Authenticate()
    {
        _accessToken = null;

        if (ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext
                as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
            if (bootstrapContext != null)
            {
                Claim subject = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                var upn = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn);
                var email = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
                var userName = upn != null ? upn.Value : email?.Value;

                _emailAddress = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;
                var userNameClaim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name");
                _fullName = userNameClaim != null ? userNameClaim.Value : String.Empty;
                _accessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
                _assertion = new UserAssertion(_accessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);
            }
        }
        return _accessToken != null;
    }

    public bool GetAccess(string apiResource)
    {
        bool gotAccess = false;
        AuthResult = null;
        AuthException = null;

        if (_accessToken != null || Authenticate())
        {
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _appKey);

            string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _aadInstance, _tenant);
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            bool retry = false;
            int retryCount = 0;

            do
            {
                retry = false;

                try
                {
                    AuthResult = authContext.AcquireToken(apiResource, clientCred, _assertion);
                }
                catch (AdalException ex)
                {
                    AuthException = ex;

                    if (ex.ErrorCode == "temporarily_unavailable")
                    {
                        retry = true;
                        retryCount++;
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw (ex);
                    }
                }
            } while ((retry == true) && (retryCount < 1));

            if (AuthResult != null && AuthResult.AccessToken != null)
            {
                gotAccess = true;
            }
        }
        return gotAccess;
    }
```

Comment: This seems a bit spammy at first, but I'm not flagging it as such because it clearly contains a programming question and does not appear to be promoting anything. I would advise editing it to make it look less spammy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, you were developing an single tenant application which calling the downstream web API(Office 365 API) in your web API.

If you were using the cache to acquire the token in your web API, it will not acquire the new token unless the token is expired. And in this scenario, there is no need to consent/reconsent to update the permission.

Please ensure that you web API is acquire the token from new request instead of cache. If you were using the **DbTokenCache**, you can clear the cache by deleting the token cache records in **PerWebUserCaches** table in the database.

**Note**

In the describing scenario above, since the downstream web API(Office 365 API) get the token using the token issued for your web API which require users sign-in. So only the **delegated permission** work in the scenario( **scp** claim in the token instead of **roles**).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of cache you think we might be using? We are not using any kind of db cache for the tokens. Thank you.

Comment: It is hard to elaborate the kinds of cache, because users can implement it themselves. Would you mind sharing the code how you construct the `AuthenticationContext` class in the web API project?

Comment: To make sure I understood correctly, I want to confirm with you that you were acquire the token for your web API, then the web API use this token to exchange the token for Office365 API. If I understood correctly, can you capture the request for the web API that exchange the token for Office 365 API?

Comment: I am not able to get that request because of this error: `AADSTS90093: Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.` This occurs when the client is trying to log into our service API and this code runs:

        `if (promptType == WebTokenRequestPromptType.ForceAuthentication ||
            result?.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.UserInteractionRequired)
        {
            result = (acc == null) ?
            await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wtr) :
            await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wtr, acc);
        }`

Comment: `AADSTS90093:...lack of permissions` is caused you were using the permission which requires **admin** to give the consent. To fix this issue, you can use the admin to grant the consent for you company first, then others are not necessary to give the consent when they visit the application first time. To use the **admin consent**, we can construe the request and append the **prompt** parameter with the value **admin_consent**. More detail about the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow, you can refer [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) .

Comment: (1) I added `wtr.Properties.Add("prompt", "admin_consent");` which resulted in error `AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators.`

(2) When I review our required permissions for Microsoft.Exchange in the azure portal (App registrations > our app name > settings > required permissions > enable access), all of our permissions, including the recent one we added - Mail.ReadWrite.All, are "Delegated Permissions" and say "No" for requiring admin consent.

Comment: Would you mind sharing all the permission you have granted on the portal? And is the issued fixed when you grant the admin consent use the admin account?